# Nodejs Unable to render page after successful form post request

Tags: node.js, forms, post, render

I am new to web development and nodejs so i would appreciate if someone could have a look at my code and help me understand what am i doing wrong.
I have a registration form that successfully posts a username and password (i can confirm i am seeing the submitted data inserted into my Oracledb). However, i want the users to be redirected to the next page (usersetup)once they complete the form but i get an error message reading :
**Error: Failed to lookup view "/usersetup" in views directory "/Users/username/Desktop/projectName/views"**

I am pretty sure the res.render("usersetup") line is not that simple but whatever i have tried so far after looking online for examples has failed.

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
   const regEmail=req.body.username;
   const regPassword = req.body.password;
    async function run() {
    let connection;  
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
      let result = await connection.execute(
        `INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (:EMAIL, :PASSWORD)`,
        { EMAIL : {val: regEmail}, PASSWORD : {val: regPassword}}
      );
      console.log("Rows inserted: " + result.rowsAffected);  
      console.log("ROWID of new row: " + result.lastRowid);

     res.render("/usersetup");
}
  run();

  });
```

i would like to add an error message if the registration fails and if not then redirect users to the usersetup page